# MASM invalid character

Tags: assembly, masm, visual-studio-2022

I have succesfully compiled and run the following code using Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 and calling procedure from C# code:

```
.code
MyProc1 proc
add RCX, RDX
mov RAX, RCX
ret
MyProc1 endp
end
```

however, after few changes in code the following error occurred:

```
invalid character in file (line 1)
```

coming back to code shown above - still compile error...

Comment: Just a note: writing x64 native assembly that is actually compliant with the Windows x64 ABI is a bit tricky itself. The code above does not have the correct prolog and epilog.  There's a macro file in the Windows SDK to make this easier to do. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exception-handling-x64?view=msvc-170#masm-macros).

Answer (score 1):

The solution was tricky. I recreated the file, and ensured the setting:
Tools/Options/Environment/Documents/Save as Unicode... was set true, because if it's not, Visual may damage file while saving (event if you use ASCII only!)

Comment: MASM doesn't understand the "Byte Order Marker", so you need to save it without a BOM.

Comment: I had the same issue but for me, the problem was that i had copied/pasted some of the code as a test...And in Vs, in the .asm file, it didn't show some "invisible characters" but when the same code was pasted in Sublime i could see them, basically i could see:  GetValueFromASM proc <0xa0> instead of GetValueFromASM proc which ofc was the problem.